# Cannot Move File with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Why is this error occuring?

> Moved failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
>   nil
>   file:///Users/hunterp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/89271982-A1A4-24234-8A8F-799FAED4E923/data/Containers/Data/Application/9BCF6922-A3A5-46E8-9C9E-281921323/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_1i5wz3.tmp

```
    func moveFile(fromPath: String, toThePath: String) {
        var error: NSError?
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if filemgr.moveItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: toThePath, error: &error)  {
        println("Move successful")
        } else {
            println("Moved failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func getDocPath() -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    }

 let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url) { fileURL, response, error in
     var toPath = self.getDocPath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("s.jpg")
     self.moveFile(fileURL.absoluteString!, toThePath: toPath )
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that file exists?  As a best practices of error checking, you may want to add some code using `NSFileManager` that checks for its existence first (as well as other expected errors) and handles that appropriately, leaving the vague Cocoa error as a catch all for any other weird thing.

Comment: where are you calling moveFile() method ? try fileURL.path!

Comment: because I cannot display the image. which is why I am changing the suffix through the move operation. You see why I do things now the way I do?

Comment: @PatrickLynch the file exists, i'm 99% certain

Comment: @hunterp this file is trashed by the system immediately after the download finishes

Comment: @LeoDabus but I'm moving the file in the download callback. updating code

Comment: you should use response suggestedFileName

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79869/discussion-between-hunterp-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: FYI this is the old syntax. New syntax uses throwable.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a No Such File error.  You are requesting to move a temporary file seemingly generated by the OS upon file download from the network.  Perhaps the file has been deleted by the system by the time you try to move it.

One way to diagnose the problem is by setting a breakpoint when you are about to move the file.  Print out the file path, and then check it from the Mac OS terminal.